# Keyboard/mouse do not work when connected to USB hub, but only on Fedora - works on other distros

Tags: fedora, usb, keyboard, mouse

**For the record**, the same problem happens in openSUSE, too, and the solution is the same. It is fixed in both Fedora 18 (as far as I could tell: I just booted a live CD) and openSUSE 12.3.

I installed Fedora 17 on my laptop, where I use a keyboard (Logitech K120) and mouse (generic USB mouse) connected to a hub.

Then I noticed that neither the keyboard nor the mouse worked. However:

- They do work in Arch Linux, Windows, GRUB and on the console (they only die when X starts), regardless if they're connected to a hub or not.
- If I plug the mouse/keyboard directly into the USB ports, they work properly.

This shows that neither the USB hub nor the keyboard/mouse are damaged.

lsusb of the relevant devices (USB hub, keyboard and mouse, respectively):

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 093a:2521 Pixart Imaging, Inc.
```

Any clues?

---

Editing as per sch's comments:

- The keyboard works on the console.
- The keyboard/mouse appears on `xinput list`, only when they're connected directly to the USB ports; **not** when they are connected to the hub.
- There is a change in `/proc/interrupts` when I move the mouse, even though the cursor doesn't move.
- When I plug the mouse/keyboard **through the hub**, nothing happens in the X logs. When I plug them directly I get the standard log information:

  ```
  [   407.686] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB OPTICAL MOUSE (/dev/input/mouse1)
  [   407.686] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
  [   407.686] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
  [   407.686] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB OPTICAL MOUSE (/dev/input/event8)
  [   407.686] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
  [   407.686] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'USB OPTICAL MOUSE'
  [   407.686]    Option "XkbRules" "evdev"
  [   407.686]    Option "XkbModel" "evdev"
  [   407.686]    Option "XkbLayout" "us"
  [   407.686]    Option "_source" "server/udev"
  [   407.686]    Option "name" "USB OPTICAL MOUSE"
  [   407.686]    Option "path" "/dev/input/event8"
  [   407.686]    Option "device" "/dev/input/event8"
  [   407.686]    Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/input/input30/event8"
  [   407.686]    Option "driver" "evdev"
  [   407.686] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: always reports core events
  [   407.686] (**) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Device: "/dev/input/event8"
  [   407.686] (--) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Vendor 0x93a Product 0x2521
  [   407.686] (--) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found 9 mouse buttons
  [   407.686] (--) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found scroll wheel(s)
  [   407.686] (--) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found relative axes
  [   407.686] (--) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Found x and y relative axes
  [   407.686] (II) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Configuring as mouse
  [   407.686] (II) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: Adding scrollwheel support
  [   407.686] (**) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
  [   407.686] (**) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
  [   407.687] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/input/input30/event8"
  [   407.687] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB OPTICAL MOUSE"  (type: MOUSE, id 17)
  [   407.687] (II) evdev: USB OPTICAL MOUSE: initialized for relative axes.
  [   407.687] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
  [   407.687] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) acceleration profile 0
  [   407.687] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
  [   407.687] (**) USB OPTICAL MOUSE: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
  ```

Comment: Both from X and the console? Any change in `watch -d cat /proc/interrupts` when you move the mouse? Do they show in `xinput list`? What about the X server logs?

Comment: @sch edited my question to answer your questions

Comment: Figured it, a known bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=823815#c7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is a known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=823815#c7) in Fedora 17. The `/lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules` has a rule for a "[Mimo 720](http://www.mimomonitors.com/products/mimo-720-s)" device (an USB monitor with its own USB hub) which uses the same chipset (thus the same USB ID) for this task.

However, because I am not using a Mimo 720, it gets misconfigured.

Solution is editing `/lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules` and commenting the line

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="058f", ATTR{idProduct}=="6254", ENV{ID_AUTOSEAT}="1"
```

Then it works perfectly.  In fact, checked on Arch Linux and it uses a different strategy to detect that device:

```
# Mimo 720, with integrated USB hub, displaylink graphics, and e2i
# touchscreen. This device carries no proper VID/PID in the USB hub,
# but it does carry good ID data in the graphics component, hence we
# check it from the parent. There's a bit of a race here however,
# given that the child devices might not exist yet at the time this
# rule is executed. To work around this we'll trigger the parent from
# the child if we notice that the parent wasn't recognized yet.
```